# Си массив указателей на функции с разными типами аргументов

Tags: c

Можно ли создать на *Cи* массив указателей на функции, но с разными аргументами и их количеством?

Использую:

```
char (*func[])(char**)={
&func1,
&func2.
}
```

Но хотелось бы функции с разными аргументами.

Comment: Поскольку все равно без явного приведения типа через этот массив вы их вызывать не сможете, приводите к, скажем, `void*`.

Comment: Использую такой массив для вызова функций на tcp сервере, для поиска нужной есть второй массив с именами функций, такой вариант использовать приятнее чем if,  а других идей не было.

Comment: Такого в Си сделать нельзя. Так же как нельзя создать массив в котором будут вперемежку int и float. Но можно использовать хитрые типы С++ или запустить интерпретатор который в рантайме будет вызывать какие угодно функции с какими угодно аргументами без всякой трансляции. :-)

Comment: На чистом си без с++?

Comment: @Игорь "На чистом си без с++?" Какие-то религиозные мотивы отказа от С++? :-) Конечно написать можно (почти)все. В конце концов все транслируется в ассемблер так что можно сразу писать на ассемблере только зачем если есть инструменты высокого уровня. Сейчас попытаюсь набросать решение со структурами и полем типа функции. Ждите. :-)

Comment: Можно сказать религиозные, пишу под ПЛИС, тамошний процессор с++ конечно может но с трудом.

Comment: Если функции должны иметь "разные аргументы и их количество", то что в вашем примере делает этот `char **`?

Comment: "такой вариант использовать приятнее чем if, а других идей не было". Есть еще `switch`. GCC, начиная с пяти `case` может скомпилировать это в табличные джампы. Еще есть вызов `dlopen` и связанные с ним, то есть для поиска функции по имени не обязательно создавать массив функций. Для защиты от вызова произвольной функции клиентским запросом, например, делаете всем нужным функциям в имени префикс `command_`. Кстати, если клиент передает в запросе вызываемую функцию по имени, то нужен все-таки хеш, а не массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что получилось:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum funtype{funtype_none=0,funtype_one=1, funtype_two=2, funtype_three=3};

struct funshell{
funtype ft;
void* funptr;
};

void fun1(){
printf("\nfun without arg");    

}

void fun2(int arg){
printf("\nfun with int arg=%i",arg);    
}

void fun3(float arg){
printf("\nfun with float arg=%f",arg);    
}

typedef void (*pfun1)();
typedef void (*pfun2)(int arg);
typedef void (*pfun3)(float arg);

#define NUMFUN 10

int main(){

funshell fsh[NUMFUN];

int i;

void* runptr;

for(i=0;i!=NUMFUN;++i){
fsh[i].ft=funtype_none;
fsh[i].funptr=NULL;
}

fsh[0].ft=funtype_one;
fsh[1].ft=funtype_two;
fsh[2].ft=funtype_three;

fsh[0].funptr=(void*)(&fun1);
fsh[1].funptr=(void*)(&fun2);
fsh[2].funptr=(void*)(&fun3);

for(i=0;i!=NUMFUN;++i){

if(fsh[i].ft==funtype_none) break;

switch(fsh[i].ft){

case funtype_one:

runptr=fsh[i].funptr;
((pfun1)(runptr))();

break;

case funtype_two:

runptr=fsh[i].funptr;
((pfun2)(runptr))(1);

break;

case funtype_three:

runptr=fsh[i].funptr;
((pfun3)(runptr))(2.2);

break;

}//switch

}//for

printf("\nend example");    

return 0;
}
```

Тестировалось на http://cpp.sh/. Это конечно С++ транслятор, но я постарался не употреблять С++ конструкций.

Да, аргументы для функций придется тоже брать из какого-то двумерного массива с признаком типа функции и номера вызова. Сейчас я аргументы для функций тупо забил прямо в код. Сейчас в этом примере аргумент для функции fun2 с аргументом int равен 1 а аргумент для функции fun3 с аргументом float равен 2.2.

UPD1:

А еще можно воспользоваться функциями с переменным числом параметров. Почитать что это такое можно здесь например.

https://learnc.info/c/vararg_functions.html

Или погуглить, про них в любом учебнике по языку Си есть.

UPD2:

По просьбе читателей вот вариант с хранением указателя на функцию не в указателе на void*, а в указателе на функцию:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum funtype{funtype_none=0,funtype_one=1, funtype_two=2, funtype_three=3};

typedef void (*pfunstore)();

struct funshell{
funtype ft;
pfunstore funptr;
};

void fun1(){
printf("\nfun without arg");    

}

void fun2(int arg){
printf("\nfun with int arg=%i",arg);    
}

void fun3(float arg){
printf("\nfun with float arg=%f",arg);    
}

typedef void (*pfun1)();
typedef void (*pfun2)(int arg);
typedef void (*pfun3)(float arg);

#define NUMFUN 10

int main(){

funshell fsh[NUMFUN];

int i;

pfunstore runptr;

for(i=0;i!=NUMFUN;++i){
fsh[i].ft=funtype_none;
fsh[i].funptr=NULL;
}

fsh[0].ft=funtype_one;
fsh[1].ft=funtype_two;
fsh[2].ft=funtype_three;

fsh[0].funptr=(pfunstore)(&fun1);
fsh[1].funptr=(pfunstore)(&fun2);
fsh[2].funptr=(pfunstore)(&fun3);

for(i=0;i!=NUMFUN;++i){

if(fsh[i].ft==funtype_none) break;

switch(fsh[i].ft){

case funtype_one:

runptr=fsh[i].funptr;
((pfun1)(runptr))();

break;

case funtype_two:

runptr=fsh[i].funptr;
((pfun2)(runptr))(1);

break;

case funtype_three:

runptr=fsh[i].funptr;
((pfun3)(runptr))(2.2);

break;

}//switch

}//for

printf("\nend example");    

return 0;
}
```

Тоже тестировалось на http://cpp.sh/.

UPD3:

Подумал я тут на досуге об этой задаче. Не нужно здесь ни массива указателей на функции, ни преобразования типов этих указателей. Все можно и нужно сделать гораздо проще:

Собственно идея в том, что явно создавать массив указателей на функции с разными прототипами не нужно. Роль массива исполнит функция, которая будет вызывать требуемые функции по индексу.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun1(){
printf("\nfun without arg");    
}

void fun2(int arg){
printf("\nfun with int arg=%i",arg);    
}

void fun3(float arg){
printf("\nfun with float arg=%f",arg);    
}

void fun_array_emulation(int funindex,int arg1,float arg2){

switch(funindex){

default:break;

case 0:fun1();break;
case 1:fun2(arg1);break;
case 2:fun3(arg2);break;

}//switch

}

#define NUMFUN 10

int main(){

int i;

for(i=0;i!=NUMFUN;++i){

fun_array_emulation(i,1,2.2);

}//for

printf("\nend example");    

return 0;
}
```

Тоже тестировалось на http://cpp.sh/.

Здесь создается запускающая функция с именем:

void fun_array_emulation(int funindex,int arg1,float arg2);

Первый агрумент у нее это псевдоиндекс функции в псевдомассиве. Сам массив указателей на функции не создается, его роль эмулирует switch внутри fun_array_emulation.

Когда надо вызвать функцию по индексу из массива, то передается индекс этой функции в массиве и аргументы. Это все заряжается в функцию fun_array_emulation и она вызывается.

Если надо передавать много аргументов, то прототип у fun_array_emulation может быть такой:

void fun_array_emulation(int funindex,int* arg1,float* arg2);

Comment: Приведение типа "указатель на функцию" к типу "указатель на данные" `void *` не определено в языке С. Указатели на функции разрешается приводить только к указателям на функции, а указатели на данные - только к указателям на данные. Поведение вашего кода не определено.

Comment: @AnT "Указатели на функции разрешается приводить только к указателям на функции, а указатели на данные - только к указателям на данные" Где это такое написано? И к тому же кто сказал что void* это указатель на данные?

Comment: @AnT "Указатели на функции разрешается приводить только к указателям на функции, а указатели на данные - только к указателям на данные". Кстати если это и так, то достаточно вместо void* использовать для хранения указателя на функцию void (*fun0)(). А перед запуском приводить ее к нужному типу функции. На всякий случай попробовал так сделать, тоже работает. А пример в ответе привел в UPD2.

Comment: @AnT "Указатели на функции разрешается приводить только к указателям на функции, а указатели на данные - только к указателям на данные". Кстати NULL можно присваивать и указателям на данные и указателям на функции. Так какого типа тогда сам NULL?

Comment: Такое написано в спецификации (в стандарте) языка С, в разделе "6.3.2.3 Pointers". О том, что к/из `void *` разрешается приводить только указатели *объектных* типов написано там же. За макро `NULL` в языке С скрывается null-pointer constant, которая обладает особым статусом и обрабатывается особым образом, что описано в том же "6.3.2.3 Pointers". То есть поведение `NULL`, каким бы типом оно ни обладало, показательным в данном случае не является.

Comment: В частности, `NULL` может быть просто `0`, т.е. иметь тип `int` и при этом неявно приводиться к любому указательному типу. Например: `int *p = 0;`. Это  однако не значит, что данное правило распространяется на весь тип `int`: в языке С не разрешается делать `int *p = 42;`. То есть, еще раз, поведение `NULL`, каким бы типом оно ни обладало, показательным в данном случае не является.

Comment: В качестве "универсального указательного типа" для функций действительно можно использовать какой-нибудь `void (*)(void)` с выполнением последующих ручных приведений. Однако, как показано в моем ответе, язык С допускает более компактное/элегантное решение.

Comment: @ AnT "язык С допускает более компактное/элегантное решение". Человеку надо запускать эти функции из массива указателей на функции в цикле. Иначе смысла нет. Если запускать их по одиночке, то можно обойтись без всяких массивов и без всяких указателей на функции. А если запускать из цикла, то не обойтись без поля типа функции.

Comment: "Иначе смысла нет" - это чересчур сильное и необоснованное утверждение. Например, некое подобие классической "таблицы виртуальных методов" с одной стороны предполагает хранение указателей на функции в массиве, а с другой не требует никаких "вызовов в цикле" или параллельного хранения типов функций.

Comment: @ AnT Для аналога таблицы вирт. методов полем типа функции является индекс в таблице вирт. методов.

Comment: @ AnT Кстати в разделе "6.3.2.3 Pointers" написано An integer may be converted to any pointer type. То есть через integer можно приравнять типы указателей на объекты и типы указателей на функции. Поэтому void* вполне может хранить указатель на функцию. Даже древние компиляторы языка Си задолго до появления С++ всегда допускали хранение указателя на функцию в типе void*.

Comment: Во-первых, язык С не дает никаких гарантий о конверсиях к/из integer types, кроме конверсий туда-сюда с `[u]intptr_t`. Все остальное является implementation-defined, то есть особенностями конкретных реализаций, к языку С прямого отношения не имеющими. Стандарт POSIX, например, может предоставлять дополнительные гарантии. Но POSIX - это POSIX, а не С.

Comment: Во-вторых, разрешать хранение указателя на функцию в `void *` "задолго до С++" язык С никак не мог :) В языке С изначально вообще не было указателей `void *`. Указатели `void *` были введены впервые в С++ и пришли в язык С именно из языка С++. В-третьих, что там "допускали древние (или какие еще) компиляторы" значения не имеет. Стандарты языка С, начиная с самого первого, такого не допускали. Любой уважающий себя компилятор языка С обязан выдать диагностическое сообщение в ответ на такую конверсию. А все остальное - это уже вопрос из области "сам себе злобный Буратино".

Comment: А еще в разделе "6.3.2.3 Pointers" написано Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Причем именно Any pointer type  а не only [u]intptr_t.

Comment: Еще раз: никто не спорит с тем, что такую конверсию можно силой выполнить с любым целым типом. Но что после этого получится - не оговаривается. А вот для `[u]intptr_t` в 7.20.1.4 дается дополнительная гарантия: конверсия из `void *` в `[u]intptr_t` и затем обратно в `void *` гарантирует восстановление изначального значения указателя. Именно эту особенность я и имел в виду.

Comment: Поосторожнее со сведениями по ссылке из UPD1 про передачу аргументов функции через стек. На многих системах (в т.ч. и 32-bit тоже)  несколько первых аргументов передаются в регистрах. И с ними прием со взятием адреса первого аргумента работать не будет. Так что, лучше всюду использовать varargs (ну, если в вашей системе его еще нет, то реализуйте сами)

Comment: Да, точно. В разделе "OLD SCHOOL" по ссылке написана полнейшая чушь. Никогда такого school в С не было.

Comment: @ AnT "А вот для [u]intptr_t в 7.20.1.4 дается дополнительная гарантия: конверсия из void * в [u]intptr_t и затем обратно в void * гарантирует восстановление изначального значения указателя." В конце концов для хранения указателя на функцию в структуре funshell можно использовать просто статический массив байтов нужной длины. Укладывать указатель на функцию в этот массив и потом восстанавливать указатель на функцию из этого массива при вызове функции. Будет еще один параметр в программе, зависящий от платформы - размер указателя на функцию. Пример я уж не буду делать.

Answer (score 3):

Если интерпретировать ваш вопрос буквально, то да, можно, если воспользоваться "классическим" свойством языка С, которое говорит, что объявление функционального типа со списком параметров `()` не оговаривает/не ограничивает количество и типы параметров.

Например

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

int bar(double x, double y, double z)
{
  return x * y * z;
}

int main()
{
  int (*f[])() = { foo, bar };
  int a = f[0](2, 3);
  int b = f[1](1., 2., 3.);
}
```

Разумеется, за правильность вызова функций через такие указатели, т.е. за указание правильного количества и типов аргументов в каждом вызове, отвечаете вы сами.

Формально это свойство языка является obsolescent, т.е. устаревшим и подлежащим удалению в будущем. Но оно является таковым аж с самого первого стандарта С. Из спецификации языка его пока не удалили и, вполне возможно, так никогда и не удалят.

Comment: А как раньше когда был только си решали проблему обработки множества команд на серверах?

Comment: @AnT как реализовать подобную реализацию средствами С++